# Crontab doesn't execute correctly

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, cron

I want my script checkbat.sh to show an xmessage if the battery status is too low. Executing the script in the terminal via

```
bash /usr/local/bin/checkbat.sh
```

works just fine. In order to add it to the cronjobs I first did

```
sudo crontab -e
```

and then added the following line:

```
*/5 * * * * bash /usr/local/bin/checkbat.sh
```

Which should execute the script every five minutes. Yet, nothing happens. Any ideas?

Comment: does your user has read permissions to the file/path

Comment: I think so. As I said, the script executes correctly via the terminal.

Comment: Does your script have to run with elevated (root) access?  If not, just run `crontab -e` without the sudo in front of it.  Plus, if you do have to run it as root, `sudo crontab -e` doesn't work for root items.  Usually just editing the `/etc/crontab` file and adding there works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

How do you know it's not executing?    Can you show us the script?

The most common problem is that your script outputs to the console.  In cron, the console doesn't exist.  Make sure your script writes to a file or directly to a console device.

On the console where you want to see the message - run: tty That will show you the device you are using in that terminal session. Then use that device name like this: /usr/bin/myscript.sh > /dev/tty 2>&1 That will push all tty output into that device and also push all error output to the same device. WARNING: If you are opening and closing tty sessions, you can't rely on this method. Most cron jobs are designed to write directly to text files and those text files are monitored somehow

Comment: How do I make the script output to a console?

Comment: On the console where you want to see the message - run:   tty

That will show you the device you are using in that terminal session.

Then use that device name like this:

/usr/bin/myscript.sh > /dev/tty 2>&1

That will push all tty output into that device and also push all error output to the same device.

WARNING:  If you are opening and closing tty sessions, you can't rely on this method.

Most cron jobs are designed to write directly to text files and those text files are monitored somehow.

Comment: Yeah that doesn't work for my purposes as I want this to work regardless of the terminals I've already opened. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with launching X programs from scripts is that they're missing important environment variables, like which display to use.

Make sure that, at the top of the script you're calling in your crontab, you have set the X display variables:

```
export DISPLAY=':0'
export XAUTHORITY='/home/your-user-here/.Xauthority'
```

Your X display may be different; you can check by running `echo $DISPLAY` in a terminal on your X session.

Answer (score 2):

crontab jobs don't have the environment set up the way an interactive job does. You have to make sure in your script that you're not relying on environment variables that are undefined.